# How to add android sliding down and sliding up gestures like AOSP QS Panel to my custom quick settings panel?

Tags: java, android

I want to create an android app that will contain a sliding panel from the top of the screen similar to android Quick Settings panel. When I swipe down from the top of the screen, a custom Quick Settings panel layout will be shown. And When I swipe up, the panel will be slide upwards. I want to make the sliding down and sliding up animations same as that of Android Quick Settings panel. I searched for the exact codes in AOSP repository. But the code for this is not in a single place. Rather it's pretty much scattered in parts there in AOSP. How to achieve this?